# Why is this sql query not giving an output?

Tags: sql

Why is my sql code producing no output?
O/P-> [Execution complete with exit code 0]

I want to query the users on their id with a limit of say 10 users & want to find posts linked only to those users. The no. of posts per user should also be 10

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT
);
-- insert some values
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 'Ryan');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (2, 'Joanna');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (3, 'Jedi');

-- create a table
CREATE TABLE posts (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  post TEXT NOT NULL,
  uid INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(uid) references users(id)
);
-- insert some values
INSERT INTO posts VALUES (1, 'hi', 2);
INSERT INTO posts VALUES (2, 'hello', 2);
INSERT INTO posts VALUES (10, 'hola', 3);
-- fetch some values

SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE uid =
(SELECT id FROM users);
```

Comment: Try: WHERE uid IN (SELECT id FROM users);

Comment: exit code 0? I'd expect an error here.

Answer (score 1):

As Nick already commented, it is `IN` you should use:

```
SQL> select p.*
  2  from posts p
  3  where p.uid in (select u.id from users u);

        ID POST                        UID
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 hi                            2
         2 hello                         2
        10 hola                          3
```

A few more options you might be interested in:

Join:

```
SQL> select p.*
  2  from posts p join users u on u.id = p.uid;

        ID POST                        UID
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 hi                            2
         2 hello                         2
        10 hola                          3
```

Exists:

```
SQL> select p.*
  2  from posts p
  3  where exists (select null
  4                from users u
  5                where u.id = p.uid
  6               );

        ID POST                        UID
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 hi                            2
         2 hello                         2
        10 hola                          3

SQL>
```

Comment: You can also add `= ANY (subquery)`.

Comment: thanks, really appreciate it, but id like to understand why my query - with = operator is not working, as in whats happening under the hood

Comment: Also what if, I want 3 users & only 3 posts from each user?